# Drupal : How to filter nodes in views based on their fivestar rating?

Tags: drupal-fivestar

There is some really good video in lullabot ,but the problem is that i have no access to it. I have selected the vote:result in the relationship of the view. Now i need to expose a filter to the user where one can select nodes based on their ratings(average/percentage etc.)

I have come across the term called voting aggregate function. How do i use it? Do we need to write a function? I am using drupal 6.

Comment: I got it. The answer lies in configuring the relationship . Configure value type and the aggregate function. I still wonder how to use 'other' options in aggregate function drop down list.Check out votingapi_cache tables in your database, you will understand more clearly !

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question and mark it accepted (after allotted time has passed)

Comment: I'd also like to see this solution.